# tar extract into working copy unversions

Tags: windows, svn, cygwin, tar

As part of our build system we generate some .tar files which we extract into a working copy and commit. This has been working fine for some years. (on windows using cygwin tar).

Now, for some reason, after the extract the folders in the working seem to be unversioned (**svn status** gives ?) and so the commit does nothing.
This happens even if we checkout a new working copy. svn client is 1.7 and was not updated since this was last working (TTBOMK).

Comment: You untar subtrees under **new name**. SY, CO

Comment: I think you're missing a verb somewhere or maybe an adverb. I cannot tell if this is a comment, a command, a suggestion or an observation. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

False alarm. Seems the tar file had an intermediate folder missing.